# How can I solve a Clobber error for the installation of Trimmomatic?

Tags: python, windows, conda, anaconda3

I'm trying to install Trimmomatic with Conda (Windows PC) but this is the error I see:
CondaVerificationError: The package for trimmomatic located at C:\Users\Utente\anaconda3\pkgs\trimmomatic-0.39-hdfd78af_2
appears to be corrupted. The path 'share/trimmomatic'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

ClobberError: The package 'defaults/win-64::openjdk-11.0.13-h2bbff1b_0' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'library/bin/freetype.dll'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.

Clobber error is repeated for other .dll files.

I have already tried "clean --all" and "update --all" but it doesn't work. I also tried to uninstall and install Conda and Python but nothing change. I thought the problem was the presence of multiple folders because I installed Conda more times but deleting every folder doesn't help me.
I thank you in advance if you will help me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what, but there seems to be somethin wrong with symbolic links inside the trimmomatic package that does not work under windows.

Try to create an environemnt with openjdk:

```
conda create -c conda-forge --override-channels -n trimmomatic openjdk
```

Then download the [binary manually](http://www.usadellab.org/cms/uploads/supplementary/Trimmomatic/Trimmomatic-0.39.zip), extract it and then run

```
conda activate trimmomatic
java -jar Trimmomatic-0.39\trimmomatic-0.39.jar
```

Thereby, adjust `Trimmomatic-0.39\trimmomatic-0.39.jar` to point to the `.jar` file that is inside the folder that you have extracted from the downloaded .zip file

Comment: Thank you for your answer! this is the answer of Conda: Error: Unable to access jarfile Trimmomatic-0.39\trimmomatic-0.39.jar.

Comment: The .jar file is in the folder you extracted from the downloaded .zip file. You might need to adjust the path to match where you put the extracted folder

Comment: Do you mean that I should cut the .jar file and bring it to trimmomatic env? Sorry it's all new for me

Comment: No, no need to copy it to any specific location. Put it somewhere on your harddrive where it is convenient. Then you will need to specify the path either absolute or relative to the .jar file when calling like I posted above.

Comment: Let's assume the trimmomatic folder you extracted is in `C:\Users\username\Downloads\Trimmomatic-0.39`, then you would run `java -jar C:\Users\username\Downloads\Trimmomatic-0.39\trimmomatic.jar`

Comment: Okay I installed Trimmomatic as usual (conda install -c bioconda trimmomatic), then I create the env and then I did the call to select the trimmomatic.jar file in the folder it was downloaded. This was the result: Usage:PE [-version] [-threads <threads>] [-phred33|-phred64] [-trimlog <trimLogFile>] [-summary <statsSummaryFile>] [-quiet] [-validatePairs] [-basein <inputBase> | <inputFile1> <inputFile2>] [-baseout <outputBase> | <outputFile1P> <outputFile1U> <outputFile2P> <outputFile2U>] <trimmer1>...

Comment: or: SE [-version] [-threads <threads>] [-phred33|-phred64] [-trimlog <trimLogFile>] [-summary <statsSummaryFile>] [-quiet] <inputFile> <outputFile> <trimmer1>...
   or: -version

Comment: Looks like it is working. That is the usage of trimmomatic

Comment: you are right, sorry I'm trying to solve this issue from Monday and my brain is dead. So every time I want to use Trimmomatic should I run the commands you wrote or I only need to enter in Trimmomatic env?

Comment: You will need to activate the conda env `conda activate trimmomatic` and then run the `java -jar` command

Comment: Okay it's clear, thank you so much for your support.

Comment: Although this answer was for the question asked in this thread, it also helped me solve a problem for my conda when creating a new environment, which resulted in many `ClobberError`s (on windows). The options `-c conda-forge --override-channels` are incredibly useful and prevent installation of unnecessary site packages.